# NGINX add two variable/arguments numbers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up an Nginx, where I want to add two numbers together.

```
server {
        server_name "~^pr-(\d*).review-apps.example.com$";
        
        location / {
            set $port 50000+$1;
            proxy_pass "http://localhost:$port/test";
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work . (Result is in string. For example "50000+125")

How can I add two numbers in nginx.conf? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use fixed length numbers, for example only three digits, for this particular case you can use string concatenation instead of adding numbers:

```
server {
    server_name "~^pr-(\d{3}).review-apps.example.com$";
        
    location / {
        set $port 50$1;
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:$port/test";
    }
}
```

This will give you exactly `50145` for the `pr-125.review-apps.example.com` hostname.

For variable count of port number digits you can use named regex capture group:

```
server {
    server_name  "~^pr-(?<pr1>\d).review-apps.example.com$"
                 "~^pr-(?<pr2>\d{2}).review-apps.example.com$"
                 "~^pr-(?<pr3>\d{3}).review-apps.example.com$";

    location / {
        if ($pr1) { set $port 5000$pr1; }
        if ($pr2) { set $port 500$pr2; }
        if ($pr3) { set $port 50$pr3; }
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:$port/test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use math with standard modules. There might be a chance with `lua` module but you probably shouldn't as NGINX wasn't meant to be used like that. It is like using a screwdriver to hammer a nail - it is possible that you succeed but it is also possible that you poke out an eye along the way.

I suggest you reconsider the design of your application, perhaps there is a better/commonly used way to achieve what you want.