# Nginx variable with regexp

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've an nginx configuration for about 40+ nodes server all written like:

```
location /39/api {
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:3138;
}

location /io39 {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:3138;
}

location /40/api {
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:3139;
}

location /io40 {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:3139;
}
```

As you can see the target node port increases with the ID into the /io39 and /39/api path, I know I can capture the number with a regexp into the location directive, but how can I increase the variable as an integer and use it as the destination port of the proxy, so I can write an unique directive for thousand ports ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there was an [evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16986549/7121513) regex modifier in Perl and PHP prior to 5.5, as far as I know there is no any equivalent for nginx and no regex mathematics is possible. One of the possible techniques described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67445641/7121513) answer. For example, you can add something like `30000` this way (I use the longest 4-digit regex pattern as first because regex matching locations are checked from first to last one):

```
location ~ "^/(\d{4})/api" {
    set $port 3$1;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/io(\d{4})" {
    set $port 3$1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/(\d{3})/api" {
    set $port 30$1;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/io(\d{3})" {
    set $port 30$1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/(\d{2})/api" {
    set $port 300$1;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/io(\d{2})" {
    set $port 300$1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/(\d)/api" {
    set $port 3000$1;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/io(\d)" {
    set $port 3000$1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}
```

This will give you port number 30001 for `/1/api` or `/io1` (as well as for `/01/api` or `/io01`), port number 30002 for `/2/api` or `/io2` and so on up to 39999 for `/9999/api` or `/io9999` URIs.

The other way is to use [`lua-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) or [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/):

```
location ~ "^/(?<number>\d{1,4})/api" {
    set_by_lua_block $port { return ngx.var.number + 3099 }
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}

location ~ "^/io(?<number>\d{1,4})" {
    set_by_lua_block $port { return ngx.var.number + 3099 }
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://172.31.32.233:$port;
}
```

Comment: very usefull, I found the first way as a viable solution. Thanks !